# cannot inflate layout in onCreateView of fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, layout-inflater

In my MenuContentActivity, I call the IntercomFragment like the following:

```
IntercomFragment myContent= IntercomFragment.newInstance(index);
FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.add(android.R.id.content, myContent, "intercomFrag").commit();
```

Then in my IntercomFragment, I try to inflate the layout "**intercom**", but it fails! It throws "`java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mycompany.myapp/com.mycompany.myapp.MenuContentActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f030030`"

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View mainView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.intercom, container, false);
......
......
......
}
```

`inflater.inflate` fails. `R.layout.intercom` exsits, **intercom.xml** is already in the layout directory. 
I can call and show my other fragments in the same way, but i didnt understand why i cannot call and show the IntercomFragment in the same way.
What is this error, any idea?

Comment: Clean your project and run again.

Comment: @PiyushGupta this is a common solution to all problems but it didn't work for me:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized that my application doesn't crash in `landspace` mode then i suspected from `intercom` layout itself.

The layout includes other layouts with  `<include layout=""......\>`

I realized that one of the included layout has only `landspace` file(in layout-land folder). So i guess because of that when loading the layout file it cannot find the `portrait` version of the included layout so it fails.

I just added the missing layout file and it is solved now!

Comment: I was going to comment to make sure you had the files in the correct resource folder. Good to see my first instinct was on the right lines :p.